# Disabling field analyzing by default in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to enable indexing of elastic search fields selectively for a type?

Through the mapping settings for a specific index,  one can set the property

{ "index" : "not_analyzed" }

For a specific field. Since my document has too many fields and is likely to change structure in the future, I would need a mapping where fields are not analyzed by default unless specified differently.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes - have a look at [dynamic templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates)

Try the following:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "notanalyzed": {
                  "match":              "*", 
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                      "type":        "string",
                      "index":       "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

The dynamic template is for new fields that aren't covered by your mapping - from the docs:

> With dynamic_templates, you can take complete control over the mapping
>   that is generated for newly detected fields.

You can also vary the mapping according to the field name, e.g. use `"match": "*_data"`, to have a different set of mappings for field names ending in "_data".

Comment: what about the fields I want to be analyzed?

Comment: the dynamic template is for new fields that aren't covered by your mapping - "With dynamic_templates, you can take complete control over the mapping that is generated for newly detected fields."  You can also vary the mapping according to the field name, e.g. use "match": "*_data", to have a different set of mappings for fields ending in "_data".

Answer (score 4):

From elasticsearch 5.x *string* type is disabled. Instead elasticsearch has introduced two types *text* and *keyword*. Read this blog for the reasons for migrating data https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

So instead of adding a template to disable analyzer, you could simply use field.keyword for exact search. 
e.g. If field name is fullName, and you have entries

1. fullName:"John Doe"
2. fullName:"John"

then, fullName:"John" will return two results, while fullName.keyword:"John" will return single record.

Just in case, you still want to disable text field, you can use the below dynamic template,

```
PUT _template/disable_all_analyzer
   {
     "template": "*",
     "mappings": {
       "_default_": {
           "dynamic_templates": [
               { "notanalyzed": {
                     "match":              "*", 
                     "match_mapping_type": "string",
                     "mapping": {
                         "type":        "keyword"
                     }
                  }
               }
             ]
          }
      }
   }
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ashay code works properly, but as it does not include an index directive the documents will be stored but not indexed, so you will not able to searches or aggregations.

I suggest include it next way:

```
PUT _template/disable_all_analyzer
   {
     "template": "*",
     "mappings": {
       "_default_": {
           "dynamic_templates": [
               { "notanalyzed": {
                     "match":              "*", 
                     "match_mapping_type": "string",
                     "mapping": {
                         "type":        "keyword",
                         "index":    "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }
               }
             ]
          }
      }
   }
```