# In Elasticsearch, how to have an index with automatic mapping and all fields are not analyzed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to do:

```
PUT /index_name/

{ "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" :"not_analyzed"            
       }
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure it is the right way...

Edit:

I applied both methods from the answers. But I have no way to test it. If in fact it do

```
 GET /index_name/_mapping
...
  "metaData_requestHeaders_accept-language": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metaData_requestHeaders_akamai-origin-hop": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metaData_requestHeaders_alexatoolbar-alx_ns_ph": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metaData_requestHeaders_authorization": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metaData_requestHeaders_c": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metaData_requestHeaders_cache-control": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metaData_requestHeaders_ckiooe": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
...
```

as you can see the automatic mapping does not show what analyzer is used. So I have no way to test that this is actually working. Any ideas?

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570365/disabling-field-analyzing-by-default-in-elastic-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dynamic Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) like :

```
PUT my_index
{
"mappings": {
  "my_type": {
     "dynamic_templates": [
        {
           "strings": {
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
             }
          }
       ]
     }
   }
  }
```

After applying above template you should see something like this :

```
GET /my_index/_mapping

{
"my_index": {
  "mappings": {
     "my_type": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
           {
              "strings": {
                 "mapping": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "match_mapping_type": "string"
              }
           }
        ],
        "properties": {}
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Above mapping indicate that all strings will be `not_analyzed` by default.

Comment: See edit in my answer. I have one question. Does your index already  contains some string fields like `metaData_requestHeaders_accept-language' and so..

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is [Elasticsearch Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html), that allow you to create mappings dynamically.

You want something like this:

```
PUT index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type":  "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The mapping doesn't show the `"index": "not_analyzed"` property? After you created the dynamic template did you recreate the index? If not, the mapping will only be changed for any new fields that you might add, the rest will stay the same. As for a way to test, you can always try to apply a `Terms Aggregation` and if the keys in the resultant bucket are lower case and split on space and other punctuation marks then the field is analyzed.