# Setting fields to not_analyzed for Elasticsearch using PHP API

Tags: php, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

so I am getting data from SQL and using PHP API to send bulk data to elastic but elastic is taking apart all my terms in the string value fields. I am trying to set the indices to not_analyzed while doing the initial sending but It doesnt seem to be working.

Please help if you can, thanks.

Comment: You should show what steps you're doing concretely, it will be easier for people around here to help you.

Comment: This is the body of my code.
$params['body'][] =[
        'index'=>[
        '_index' => $rbc_index,
        '_type' => 'scom',
        '_id' => $i, 
        ]
];
    $params['body'][] =[
     'timestamp' => $localDate,
     'localhosttime' => $row["date"],
     'serverName' => $row["serverName"],
     'objectName' => $row["objectName"],
     'counterName' => $row["counterName"],
     'instanceName' => $row["instanceName"],
     'sampleValue' => $row["sampleValue"]
    ];

I can see the results in elastic and everything. its all just analyzed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the strings in ES are analyzed, so you need to mapping the index and say what fields especifically do you want to not be analyzed. full doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html).

for example

```
{
  "tag": {
    "type":     "string",
    "index":    "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

So, when you upload data to that index, the field tag will not be analyzed. Check if the fields set as not_analyzed in your index are matching with the fields that you are uploading the data, could be that their are not the same and the why their are being analyzed.

If you want set by default the string not analyze, check  [Disabling field analyzing by default in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570365/disabling-field-analyzing-by-default-in-elastic-search)

Comment: Yea, I looked at the document, I just dont understand where the tag statemet goes.. :S This is what my code body looks like

$params['body'][] =[
        'index'=>[
        '_index' => $rbc_index,
        '_type' => 'scom',
        '_id' => $i, 
        ]
];
    $params['body'][] =[
     'timestamp' => $localDate,
     'localhosttime' => $row["date"],
     'serverName' => $row["serverName"],
     'objectName' => $row["objectName"],
     'counterName' => $row["counterName"],
     'instanceName' => $row["instanceName"],
     'sampleValue' => $row["sampleValue"]
    ];

Comment: you can show me the index mapping or how are you doing that?