# Insert data with None of the fields indexed and create dynamic indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I have many JSON documents to be stored in elastic Search.
All the JSON documents have few fields which always exists but 
some of the fields need not exist all the time.
So Maximum there would be 5000 fields in the complete JSON.
Some of the fields can have fields which can have either string or Date Type.And New fields can also be added to new documents.

## Problems Faced:

As some of the fields,can have either date type or String type , elastic search gives an exception while inserting new documents

## Exception:

Wrong mapping type current type [Date] mapped Type [text]

## Question1:

Can we type of a field to (*) instead of Date or String that can store any type?
Can this be done after insertion or it should be declared initially and then only documents should be added?
But if new fields are to be added i have to  re-insert all the documents

## Question2:

Although there are 5000 fields can we put index only on certain fields?
If Yes how?

I want something similar to SQL:

Step 1: Create Table with 5000 columns.
Step 2: Create index only on 10 fields
Step 3: If More indexes are needed add dynamically

Are the same things possible in elastic search?

I mean the can it be done in the following way?

1.First insert documents with no fields as indexes

2.Then index only certain fields which are needed?

3.Add More indexes if required on already existing documents?

Comment: Well, I can give you a partial answer. You can try to disable analyzers by default. See this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570365/disabling-field-analyzing-by-default-in-elastic-search
That way, your new fields will not be indexed. However, that has consequences on your queries. If you choose to not analyze the fields, the the full-text feature will be gone.

Comment: Regarding the string/date conflict, dynamic templates may also help. See the link I already posted, and this doc (mentioned there anyway): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates